# How to setup feathers offline in react native

Tags: react-native, feathersjs

I would like to know if anyone successfully set up feathers offline in react native. Right now I am having an issue whenever I call "`owndataWrapper`" i.e

```
import { owndataWrapper } from '@feathersjs-offline/client';
owndataWrapper(app, '/messages', {});
```

The error says Unable to resolve module path in /node-localstorage/LocalStorage.js . . so I ended up installing these packages.

assert, constants, events, path, stream, and fs

and got a new error.

here is the error.

https://github.com/feathersjs-offline/owndata-ownnet/issues/46

My guess is probably due to the fs package, it has a security issue.

Any idea? Thanks

Comment: I read your code and on src/index.js shouldn't be `app.use('/messages', memory());`instead of `app.use('/messages', localstorage({ storage: AsyncStorage }));`?

Comment: thank you so much for the response, I will try it

Comment: so tried changing it to ```app.use('/messages', memory());``` using feather-memory but whenever I use owndataWrapper the app crash

Comment: I'm not an expert, I followed [this](https://mhillerstrom.medium.com/introducing-offline-first-enablement-for-the-feathers-framework-5bdebc0a8592) simple guide

Comment: then it start to ask me to install these packages . . fs, assert, constants, events, path stream . . but there is a problem with fs because it has security issue

Comment: @GiovanniEsposito - may I know what version of react native you are using?

Comment: I have the latest: 0.64

Answer (score 0):

After digging further it turns out it only works on web apps. It uses packages that does not exists in react native such as path, process, fs, and so on. I tried using

https://github.com/parshap/node-libs-react-native

and

https://github.com/staltz/react-native-process-shim

but got stuck and continuesly having error on fs. . in conclusion I need to drop the ball for now since this feathers offline is not yet fully created for react native.